# Mac keyboard shortcut to press the replace button

Tags: mac, keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut on a Mac that can press the replace button? See image.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press Tab to move the focus from Stop to Replace, then Space to select the focused element.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on Mac Mojave

Comment: @Joe Still works for me, do you still have All Controls enabled in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts as shown in your screenshot?